# undefined method `question_id' for nil:NilClass　とエラーが出ます

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

入門書をやっているのですがアソシエーションのところ？でうまくいかず、undefined method `question_id' for nil:NilClass　が出てきてしまいます。belongs_to, has_manyのところはちゃんとかいてるつもりなのですが。。。 
createのquestion_idのところでエラーがでます。

answers_controller.rb

```
  class AnswersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_answer, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    # GET /answers
    # GET /answers.json
    def index
      redirect_to '/questions'
    end

    # GET /answers/1
    # GET /answers/1.json
    def show
      redirect_to '/questions'
    end

    # GET /answers/new
    def new
      @answer = Answer.new
    end

    # GET /answers/1/edit
    def edit
      redirect_to '/questions'
    end

    # POST /answers
    # POST /answers.json

    def create
      end_counter = 10 #終了にする回答数
      @answer = Answer.new(answer_params)
      respond_to do |format|
        if @answer.save
        num = Answer.where('question_id = ?',@amswer.question_id).count
        if num >= end_counter then
          q = Quetion.find @answer.question_id
          q.finished = true
          q.save
        end
          format.html { redirect_to '/questions/' + @answer.question_id.to }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @answer }
        else
          format.html { render :new }
          format.json { render json: @answer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end

    # PATCH/PUT /answers/1
    # PATCH/PUT /answers/1.json
    def update
      redirect_to '/questions'
    end

    # DELETE /answers/1
    # DELETE /answers/1.json
    def destroy
      redirect_to '/questions'
    end

    private
      # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
      def set_answer
        @answer = Answer.find(params[:id])
      end

      # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
      def answer_params
        params.require(:answer).permit(:question_id, :content, :name)
      end
  end
```

answer.rb

```
class Answer < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :question

    validates :content, :name, presence: {message:'is necessary.'}
  end
```

question.rb

```
  class Question < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :answer

    validates :content, :name, presence: {message:'is necessary.'}
  end
```

Comment: タイポが原因で無事解決できました。こんなミスですみませんでした。コメントして頂いた方本当に感謝します。独学で初めてこのようなサイト利用しましたがとても助かりました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2):

> belongs_to, has_manyのところはちゃんとかいてるつもりなのですが。。。

今回のエラーの場合、そのあたりに問題がある可能性は低いでしょう。それを説明します。

「undefined method 'メソッド名' for 値:クラス名」というエラーは、「[クラス名]型の[値]に[メソッド名]が定義されていない」という意味になります。今回のエラーはどうでしょうか。

> undefined method `question_id' for nil:NilClass
>   => NilClass 型の値 nil に question_id メソッドは定義されていない

おかしいですね、Answerクラスのオブジェクトに対してquestion_idを呼び出したはずなのに、NilClassの値nilだなんて。でも逆に言えば、**Answerクラスの定義以前の問題**のようです。

```
num = Answer.where('question_id = ?',@amswer.question_id).count
```

`@amswer.question_id` としているので、`@amswer` が `nil` になっているようです。

インスタンス変数が意図せず nil になっている原因をざっくりわけると、

- どこかで nil を代入してしまっている
  (例: 初期化に使ったメソッドが nil を返した)
- [未初期化・未定義のインスタンス変数を参照している](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/doc/spec=2fvariables.html)
  (例: 変数名を間違えている)

のどちらかです。今回は後者だったわけですね。

`undefined ... for nil:NilClass` というエラーを見かけたら、まずは対象が nil になっていることに注目しましょう。大抵は **nil になっていることがおかしい**はずです。

Comment: エラーメッセージはそのように見ればよかったのですね！詳しい説明ありがとうございます。エラーメッセージの見方からちゃんと勉強していきたいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

typoです。

amswer → answer